Display Python ipycanvas standalone without Jupyter notebooks?
I love the ipycanvas library to create great graphics directly in Jupyter notebooks.
I wonder is there a way to migrate this canvas to a pure Python program, like using a standalone GUI? This would really expand the possibilities in using this great technology.
Just for a simple canvas like this:
from ipycanvas import Canvas

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
canvas.fill_style = "rgb(255,0,255)"
canvas.fill_rect(25, 25, 100, 100)
canvas.clear_rect(45, 45, 60, 60)
canvas.stroke_rect(50, 50, 50, 50)

canvas


I think this question 'Does this mean that I can't use ipycanvas in py files, if I want to export pictures (to_file) ' in an Open issue posting and the replies address this is currently not possible; however, would be solvable potentially. Not at this time though.
